# Finding no.of times small string is in large string (c++)

Tags: c++, string

I have to implement c++ code to find out the number of occurrences of a small string in a large string with overlapping allowed. For eg- if large string is acacab and small string is aca, then answer should be 2.
I'm not getting correct answer by making this code:

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<cstring>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
  int i, j, k, c=0;
  char lstr[30],sstr[10],tstr[10];
  cout<<"Enter large string:"<<endl;
  cin>>lstr;
  cout<<"Enter small string:"<<endl;
  cin>>sstr;
  for(i=0;i<strlen(lstr);i++)
  {
    if(lstr[i]==sstr[0])
    {
        j=i;
        for(k=0;k<strlen(sstr);k++,j++)
        {
            tstr[k]=lstr[j];
        }
    }
    if(strcmp(tstr,sstr)==0)
        c++;
 }
 cout<<c;
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, add a `'\0'` to terminate c-style string, and move `if(strcmp(tstr,sstr)==0)` in the `if(lstr[i]==sstr[0])` statement(otherwise you will continuing increment c when `lstr[i] != sstr[0]`):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int i, j, k, c=0;
  char lstr[30],sstr[10],tstr[10];
  cout<<"Enter large string:"<<endl;
  cin>>lstr;
  cout<<"Enter small string:"<<endl;
  cin>>sstr;
  for(i=0;i<strlen(lstr);i++)
  {
    if(lstr[i]==sstr[0])
    {
        j=i;
        for(k=0;k<strlen(sstr) && j<strlen(lstr);k++,j++)
        {
            tstr[k]=lstr[j];
        }
        tstr[k] = 0;
    //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
        if(strcmp(tstr,sstr)==0)
            c++;
    }
  }
  cout<<c;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried 'ababa' as large string and 'ab' as small string.

Comment: welcome, as John said, it's better idea use string in C++, life will be more easier :)

Answer (score 3):

It's much easier if you use C++ strings instead of C ones:

```
  int c=0;
  string lstr, sstr;
  cout<<"Enter large string:"<<endl;
  cin>>lstr;
  cout<<"Enter small string:"<<endl;
  cin>>sstr;

  for (size_t pos = 0;
       (pos = lstr.find(sstr, pos)) != string::npos;
       pos++)
  {
    c++;
  }

  cout<<c;
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, thank you. But can you tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Sorry but I'm a begginer in C++ and so I'm not able to understand what have you done! Is it STL?

Comment: No I did not use the STL at all.  The main "trick" was to use `std::string::find()` to most of the work, rather than implementing string searching yourself.  Also, my version will work with any length of strings, whereas your code is vulnerable to buffer overruns if the inputs are long.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem more efficiently in `O(n*m)` complexity, where n is large string size and m is small string size.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int i, j, k, c=0;
  char lstr[30],sstr[10];
  cout<<"Enter large string:"<<endl;
  cin>>lstr;
  cout<<"Enter small string:"<<endl;
  cin>>sstr;
  for(i=0; lstr[i]; i++) // You don't need to calculate strlen each time. This loop will break when lstr reaches null ('\0') character
  {
    if(lstr[i]==sstr[0])
    {
        for(k=0,j=i; sstr[k] && lstr[j]; k++,j++) // don't need to calculate strlen each time
        {
            if(sstr[k]!=lstr[j])  // Break if not match
                break;
        }
        if(k==strlen(sstr)) // Whole string matched
            c++;
    }
  }
  cout<<c<<"\n";
  return 0;
}
```

If you want to solve this problem in O(n) complexity you can use [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) algorithm. Which is the best choice for this kind of problems.